# Determine if the equation is valid/true

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The equation is:
$$\log_b \frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}} = 2\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}).$$

I can get as far as:
$$\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}) - \log_b(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}) = 2\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})$$

Which looks almost too simple, but I can't get the signs to match up right to solve the problem.  Do I need to further break out the logarithmic functions that are there?

Comment: Suggestion: Don't manipulate the entire "equality" unless you already know it is true; if you start with a false equality you can still end up with something "true", if your steps are not reversible. E.g., starting from $1=2$ you can easily end up with $1=1$.

Comment: Good suggestion, starting over with just the left hand side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT 1.** $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2$ for any numbers $a$ and $b$.

**HINT 2.** Note that
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}} = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^2}{3-2}.$$

Comment: It was not copied correctly, the right hand side has been edited above to say: $$2\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\log_b \frac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}} = 2\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}).$$

Since $2\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}) = \log_b((\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^2)$ and $\log_b$ is a one-to-one function, you should ask whether $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})/(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})$ is the same as $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^2$.  And for that you can rationalize the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}) - \log_b(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}) = 2\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})$$ 
is equivalent to 
$$\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}) = \log_b(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}) + 2\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})$$ 
which is equivalent to 
$$\log_b(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}) = \log_b((\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^2)$$ 
which you can multiply out to check, or you might spot $(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{3}^2-\sqrt{2}^2=1$.